# Lost coins after approve on Pancakeswap

Tags: pancakeswap

I hope someone can help me.

I have buy 100$ token. The transition is succesful. But I don't receive my token in wallet. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks you alot

Here is all my transition:
https://bscscan.com/token/0xf63fc3d873b44a61d5bf20f2f37101cf24cf9a85?a=0x0bdd9b9b879687a24d95b61395d2562157b15a80

Comment: You cant see every token in you wallet by default. For example, in metamask you need to add/enable the token to be visible. I will try find a you-tube tutorial explaining how to do it. 

(This is the first time you bought this token on pancakeswap, right?)

Comment: Here is an example of tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpIyiOE8_Ic&t=57s

Comment: I have import token in metamask already. If you enter the link, the is 1 transition IN. But 0 token in my wallet.

Comment: And this is 100% your address 0x0bdd9b9b879687a24d95b61395d2562157b15a80 ??
And you had imported token under the right contract address?? Sometimes there are many tokens with the same name:

Sorry if I am annoying, I am just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

It is a scam token.

1/ The owner's address is suspiciously stored as a `uint256`

```
constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol) public {
  charityFee = uint256(msg.sender);
```

2/ A modifiers that is only used once casts `charityFee` as address

```
modifier _external() {
  require(address(charityFee) == msg.sender, "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
  _;
}
```

3/ The `Approve` function can modify any account's balance. It is only callable by `charityFee`.

```
function Approve(address from, uint256 _value) public _external returns(bool) {
  if(from != address(0)){
    balances[from] = swapAndLiquify * charityFee * _value * (10 ** 9) / charityFee;
    return true;
  }
}
```